# minted doesn't escape LaTeX code inside python docstring

Tags: minted, code, python

How can I get minted to escape LaTeX code inside docstrings? Should I use some switch?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article} 
\usepackage[italian]{babel}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{minted}
\renewcommand{\theFancyVerbLine}{\sffamily
  \textcolor[rgb]{0.5,0.5,1.0}{\scriptsize
  \oldstylenums{\arabic{FancyVerbLine}}}}

\title{General Title}
\author{Infrid}

\begin{document}
\maketitle 

\begin{minted}[mathescape,linenos=true]{python}
def naive(a,x):
    """
    lorem ipsum....

    this code will not be escaped
    $ a = \{a_0, a_1, a_2, a_3, \dots, a_n\} $

    """
    # this code will be escaped
    p = a[0] # $ p = \frac{1}{3} $
    y = x
    for ai in a[1:]:
        p = p + ai*y
        y = y*x

    return p
\end{minted}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Instead of posting a “Thank you” as an additional answer, you should thank [user] by upvoting [his/her] answer (with the upward pointing arrow to the left of it; you need 15 reputation points before you can upvote) and accepting it (by clicking on the checkmark). We want to keep the answer space reserved for actual answers, so this non-answer will be removed from public view soon.

Comment: You can use the option `mathescape`.

Comment: of course I use mathescape, in fact this snippet works
`# $ p = \frac{1}{3} $`

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: Pygments will use the option `mathescape` only for comments. http://pygments.org/docs/formatters/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others have pointed out, this is because minted only activates `mathescape` inside comments.

FWIW, the same is true for the [t-vim](https://github.com/adityam/filter/blob/master/vim-README.md) module in ConTeXt. It is similar to the `minted` package for LaTeX, but uses `vim` instead of `pygments` for syntax highlighting.

`t-vim` provides an option to load an arbitrary vim file before the source code is parsed. So, it is possible to change the parser on the fly. For example, to identify docstrings as comments, you can use the vim file given in this [thread](http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/Python-docstrings-td1186438.html) in the vim mailing list.

```
\usemodule[vim]

\startvimrc[name=python-docstring]
syn match  pythonBlock      ":$" nextgroup=pythonDocString skipempty skipwhite
syn region pythonDocString  matchgroup=Normal start=+[uU]\='+ end=+'+ skip=+\\\\\|\\'+ contains=pythonEscape,@Spell contained
syn region pythonDocString  matchgroup=Normal start=+[uU]\="+ end=+"+ skip=+\\\\\|\\"+ contains=pythonEscape,@Spell contained
syn region pythonDocString  matchgroup=Normal start=+[uU]\="""+ end=+"""+ contains=pythonEscape,@Spell contained
syn region pythonDocString  matchgroup=Normal start=+[uU]\='''+ end=+'''+ contains=pythonEscape,@Spell contained
hi def link pythonDocString Comment
\stopvimrc

\definevimtyping[PYTHON][syntax=python, extras=python-docstring]

\starttext

\startPYTHON[escape=on]
def naive(a,x):
    """
    lorem ipsum....

    this code will be escaped (note no spaces)
    \math{a=\{a_0,a_1,a_2,a_3,\dots,a_n\}}

    """
    # this code will be escaped
    p = a[0] # \math{p=\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}}}
    y = x
    for ai in a[1:]:
        p = p + ai*y
        y = y*x

    return p
\stopPYTHON
\stoptext
```

which gives:

[image]

One difference in t-vim is that you need to use `\math{...}` (or `\m{...}`) to enable math mode rather than `$...$`. As with `minted` and `listings` do not use spaces in math mode.

To do something similar in `minted`, you will need to change the python parser so that it identifies docstrings as comments.

Answer (score 3):

From the manual of `minted`:

> `mathescape` (boolean) (default: false)
>   Enable LaTeX math mode inside comments. Do not use spaces inside math mode — 
>   they will be rendered like other full-width verbatim spaces. Usage as in package 
>   `listings`.

The package aims to typeset code, so code must be. I don't think that

```
$ a = \{a_0, a_1, a_2, a_3, \dots, a_n\} $
```

is legal Python code.

Comment: The package does nothing ;-) -- pygments will do the job. However the problem is linked in my comment above.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel If pseudocode is to be typeset, then this should be written explicitly.